# How to handle placeholders in variadic templates for a threadpool

Tags: c++, threadpool, variadic-templates, stdbind

I'm implementing a threadPool with waitable tasks. The threadPool saves tasks in a threadsafe deque, here `threadsafeQueue<function_wrapper>`. Tasks are callable objects where almost all of the arguments are bound with `std::bind` except of the last. I started with the implementation from Anthony Williams' Concurrency In Action book (Listing 9.2). I have difficulties implementing the `function_wrapper` and the variadic template function `submit` so that when a task is popped out from the deque `try_pop(task)` and executed `task()` I still can set the last argument like `task(myLastArgument)`.

This is Anthony Williams' function wrapper:

```
class function_wrapper
{
    struct impl_base {
        virtual void call() = 0;
        virtual ~impl_base() {}
    };

    std::unique_ptr<impl_base> impl;

    template<typename F>
    struct impl_type : impl_base
    {
        F f_;
        impl_type(F&& f)
        : f_(std::move(f))
        {}

        void call() { f_(); }
    };

public:

    template<typename F>
    function_wrapper(F&& f)
    : impl(new impl_type<F>(std::move(f)))
    {}

    void operator() () { impl->call(); }

    function_wrapper() = default;

    function_wrapper(function_wrapper&& other)
    : impl(std::move(other.impl))
    {}

    function_wrapper& operator=(function_wrapper&& other)
    {
        impl = std::move(other.impl);
        return *this;
    }

    function_wrapper(const function_wrapper&) = delete;
    function_wrapper(function_wrapper&) = delete;
    function_wrapper& operator=(const function_wrapper&) = delete;
};
```

This is the abbreviated threadPool:

```
template <typename T>
class threadPool
{
private:
    threadsafeQueue<function_wrapper> workQueue_;   
    std::atomic_bool done_;
    std::vector<std::thread> threads_;

    void workerThread(unsigned long thread);

        T threadData_; 

    template<typename FunctionType> 
    auto submit(FunctionType&& f)
    {
        typedef typename std::result_of<FunctionType()>::type resultType;
        std::packaged_task<resultType()> task(std::move(f));
        std::future<resultType> result(task.get_future());
        workQueue_.push(std::move(task));

        return result;
    }
};


template <typename T>
void threadPool<T>::workerThread(unsigned long thread)
{
    while (!done_)
    {
        function_wrapper task;

        if(workQueue_.try_pop(task))
        {
            task();
        }
        else
        {
            std::this_thread::yield();
        }

    }
}
```

With the shown implementation I can submit callable objects to the pool. The variadic template function `submit` creates a `std::packaged_task<resultType()>` and puts it on the deque. The worker threads run `workerThread(unsigned long thread)` and do there work by popping out the tasks previously inserted by the main thread and executing them with `task()`.

A simple example for a main function:

```
int main()
{
    threadPool<double> pool(5UL);

    auto fut = pool.submit(std::bind((void(*) (int,int))doTheWork,11,22));

    fut.wait();
}
```

What I would like to have is a submit call in my main function like:

```
auto fut = pool.submit(std::bind((void(*) (int,int))doTheWork,11,std::placeholders::_1));
```

The task execution inside my thread pool should then look like:

```
task(thread);
```

How do I have to change the variadic template function `submit` and the `function_wrapper` to achieve my goal?

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**:

I tried the function wrapper implementation from:

[Return values for active objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30854070/return-values-for-active-objects/30854998#30854998)

Now the function wrapper is moveable only and can take arguments, thanks to Yakk. But the problem now is that the new function wrapper can not handle `std::bind()` with `std::placeholders`. For example I can define a task with the new wrapper like

```
myWrapper<void(int,int)> task1 = doTheWork;
task1(66,77);
```

but I can not bind function arguments in a flexible way:

```
myWrapper<void()> task2 = std::bind(doTheWork, 66, 77); // ERROR
```

With the error in VS2019:

```
error C2440:  'initializing': cannot convert from 'std::_Binder<std::_Unforced,void (__cdecl *)(int,int),int,int>' to 'myWrapper<void (void)>'
message :  No user-defined-conversion operator available that can perform this conversion, or the operator cannot be called
```

Or when I try it with `std::placeholders`:

```
myWrapper<void(int)> task2 = std::bind(doTheWork, 66, std::placeholders::_1); // ERROR
task2(77);
```

I get the following error in VS2019:

```
error C2338:  tuple index out of bounds
message :  see reference to class template instantiation 'std::tuple_element<0,std::tuple<>>' being compiled
message :  see reference to alias template instantiation 'std::tuple_element_t<0,std::tuple<>>' being compiled
message :  see reference to function template instantiation 'const tuple_element<_Index,std::tuple<_Rest...>>::type &&std::get(const std::tuple<_Rest...> &&) noexcept' being compiled
message :  see reference to class template instantiation 'std::result_of<const F &(void)>' being compiled
message :         with
message :         [
message :             F=std::_Binder<std::_Unforced,void (__cdecl *)(int,int),int,const std::_Ph<1> &>
message :         ]
message :  see reference to alias template instantiation 'std::result_of_t<const std::_Binder<std::_Unforced,void (__cdecl *)(int,int),int,const std::_Ph<1> &>&(void)>' being compiled
message :  see reference to class template instantiation 'std::integral_constant<bool,false>' being compiled
message :  see reference to class template instantiation 'std::disjunction<_Traits...>' being compiled
error C2440:  'initializing': cannot convert from 'std::_Binder<std::_Unforced,void (__cdecl *)(int,int),int,const std::_Ph<1> &>' to 'myWrapper<void (void)>'
message :  No user-defined-conversion operator available that can perform this conversion, or the operator cannot be called
```

However with `std::function` it´s possible:

```
std::function<void(int)> task3 = std::bind(doTheWork, 66, std::placeholders::_1);
task3(77);
```

Any hints how to implement a movable only function wrapper with flexible arguments? The aim is still to use it inside a thread pool where the function wrapper is pased to a `std::packaged_task`.

Comment: `function_wrapper` looks like an attempt to reinvent `std::function`, except it hard-codes a single signature, the equivalent of `std::function<void()>`. Just drop `function_wrapper` and use `std::function<void(unsigned long)>` in its place.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik: Thanks for your comment. The ``function_wrapper`` is used because ``std::packaged_task<>`` are not copyable, just movable. There for ``std::function<>`` can not be used for the queue entries. ``std::function<>`` requires that the stored function objects are copy-constructible.

Comment: Your virtual call method takes no argument. You say you want to pass an argument to your function. Have you tried - just passing an argument to your function? What happened? I'm really unclear on what specific problem you encountered.

Comment: Ah. Well, there are some ideas [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25330716/move-only-version-of-stdfunction), but if you want to salvage `function_wrapper`, just make `call()` and `operator()` take a parameter.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik: Thanks for the hint. I implemented a moveable only function wrapper which takes parameter. But now I can not manage arguments in a flexible way. See Update of my question.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Suppose you managed to implement the wrapper the way you want - how do you plan to use this facility? By what magic is `workerThread` supposed to know which task to call with one argument and which with two? Where would it obtain those extra arguments?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik: I want to push ``std::packaged_task``s on my threadsafe queue. The ``std::packaged_task``s wraps a callable function which in my case is the ``function_wrapper``, due to the movable only restriction. As shown in my example I want to bind arguments on this callable function. One argument should remain flexible. Because inside my thread pool each thread runs ``void threadPool<T>::workerThread(unsigned long thread)``, tries to pop a task/callable function from the queue and executes it with its specific thread number  (``unsigned long thread``), which is not known beforehand.

Comment: Ah, I think I misunderstood the question. What error do you get from `myWrapper<void(int)> task2 = std::bind(doTheWork, 66, std::placeholders::_1);`? It feels like it should work.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik: Thanks for your comment. I updated my question and inserted the errors.

Comment: The error message talks about `myWrapper<void (void)>`, not `myWrapper<void(int)>`. I suspect the code you show is not the code you actually compile.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik: You are right, thanks. The error is for ``myWrapper<void()> task2 = `` ...